# Web-based GUI to query postgres db including JOIN ability?

Tags: jquery, postgresql

I'm aware of the jQuery builder, but if I understand correctly this [doesn't allow the user to join tables](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/310). Is there an alternative that allows for `join`? I'm looking for something for users who don't know how to program, and need to do something like

```
SELECT company.cat AS company_cat,
       company.name AS company_name,
       acqu.company_cat AS acqu_cat,
       acqu.acquired_cat AS acqu_date
  FROM home.base_company company
  LEFT JOIN home.base_acqu acqu
    ON company.cat = acqu.company_cat
 ORDER BY 1
```

Do I have to create my own query builder for this?

Comment: It's quite some years ago that I last used PostgreSQL, but I remember they have a web interface named [phpPgAdmin](https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin) which might support this as well. [Wikipedia lists some more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration), e.g. [TeamPostgreSQL](http://www.teampostgresql.com/), which might be worth a look while you're waiting for answers. Good luck!

Comment: Constructing a db query requires a different mental model than most conventional programming (logical programming aka Prolog set aside), so are you sure that your users are not up to the task of issueing SQL commands straight away? After all, the relational model is mathematical by nature and to a large extent applied set theory. Imho, representing not just conditions but whole queries in and/or tree structures as jQueryBuilder uses seems rather more but less challenging than writing sql.